# Array Limitando via POST

Tags: php, html, array

Galera, tava apanhando no meu código sempre dando erro de offset e coisas do gênero, quando descobri que de alguma maneira meu array não está vindo completo.

Eu tenho um formulário, onde ele é alimentado de acordo com os resultados do banco de dados.

```
<?php
$Despesas = new Read();
$Despesas->ExeRead("tb_contas", "WHERE id_condominio = :idC AND fg_ativo = '1' ORDER BY nm_nome ASC", "idC={$cond}");
var_dump($Despesas->getRowCount());
?>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tb-despesas">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Conta(s)</th>
            <th>Valor Cobrar</th>
            <th>Valor Real</th>
            <th>Referente</th>
            <th>Consumo</th>
            <th>Medidas</th>
            <th>Obs.</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        foreach($Despesas->getResult() as $Despesa):
        ?>
            <tr>
                <input name="id_despesa[]" type="hidden" value="<?=$Despesa['id'];?>"> //Aqui passo um hidden pois faço uma verificação depois do ID correto
                <td><?=$Despesa['nm_nome']?></td>
                <td><input name="vl_valor[]" class="form-control" type="number"></td>
                <td><input name="vl_valorreal[]" class="form-control" type="number"></td>
                <td><input name="nm_referencia[]" id="dt" class="form-control" onkeypress="mascara(this, '##/####')" type="text"></td>
                <td><input name="consumo[]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td><input name="medidas[]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
                <td><input name="obs[]" class="form-control" type="text"></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
        endforeach;
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Envio isso via `POST`pra mesma página onde vou tratando e depois gravo no banco de dados. Ai começa a confusão. Em uma pesquisa em específico, me vem 160 resultados, mas quando vou tratar depois do post estou recebendo apenas 143, quando tento pegar os últimos resultados fica dando erros de offset pois ele não existe.

Quando faço uma outra operação onde me retornam menos índices, na casa dos 50, tudo funciona lindamente =P

Já até mudei meu post_max_size entre outros pontos no php.ini, mas não acho que sejam tantos resultados a ponto de chegar ao limite.

Alguém tem ideia se isso é realmente algum limite de envio via post ou estou errando em algum lugar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No final o problema estava de fato no apache. Uma linha chamada `max_input_vars` estava comentada no arquivo `php.ini`.

Retirando o comentário funcionou normalmente. A linha completa no `php.ini` está assim:

```
; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted
max_input_vars = 2500
```