# Existe ajuste a ser realizado para definir um número máximo de elementos enviados/recebidos num array via POST no php?

Tags: php, array

Seguinte pessoal,

Estou enfrentando um problema em um sistema em que estou trabalhando, no qual eu estou tentando enviar/receber array que não está chegando completo.

Após alguns testes identifiquei que o problema está no número total de elementos constantes nesse array, e não ao volume de dados propriamente dito.

Cheguei a essa conclusão após verificar que quanto menos variáveis eu enviava por linha, mais linhas eu conseguia receber.

Aí resolvi contar o número de elementos que estavam chegando nesse array e percebi que variaram entre 987 e 998 elementos (independente o seu conteúdo, tipo com 7 dados na linha recebi 141 linhas = total 987 elementos; com 6 dados recebi 165 linhas = 990 elementos, com 5 dados recebi 198 linhas = 990 elementos, 4 dados, 248 linhas = 992 elementos).

Levando isso em conta, há algo que eu deva fazer no php ou na configuração do servidor pra ampliar isso para pelo menos umas 1000 linhas independente do número de dados enviados por linha?

Detalhe que possa ser relevante, o servidor utilizado roda o php 5.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40768/v%C3%A1ri%C3%A1vel-post-tem-limite-de-tamanho

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/343010/array-limitando-via-post